# Scrape tables with python for player lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the EA sports football tables for players to this website:

https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/fut/database/results?position_secondary=LF,CF,RF,ST,LW,LM,CAM,CDM,CM,RM,RW,LWB,LB,CB,RB,RWB

I have run this simple code however I am unable to get any output
code:

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/fut/database/results?position_secondary=LF,CF,RF,ST,LW,LM,CAM,CDM,CM,RM,RW,LWB,LB,CB,RB,RWB')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
contents = soup.find(class_='contrast-white')
```

Can anybody help me with it please?

Comment: Can you share the expected output? By the way, I am not able to find any element with that class on the provided url on my browser.

Comment: Hi @bla the expected output would be: 
`CRISTIANO RONALDO OVR POS PAC DRI SHO DEF PAS PHY
TEAM OF THE YEAR 99 LW 98 99 99 50 94 95

CRISTIANO RONALDO
TEAM OF THE SEASON GOLD 99 ST 97 98 99 47 93 96

CRISTIANO RONALDO
FUT CHAMPIONS GOLD 99 ST 97 98 99 47 93 96

SUÁREZ
FESTIVAL OF FUTBALL 99 ST 94 99 99 61 97 96

PELÉ
ICONS   98 ST 95 96 96 60 93 76
OVR

MESSI
TEAM OF THE YEAR 98 RW 96 99 97 45 98 81`
Also what should be the class in this case? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with that page is that those elements are dynamically generated by javascript.

Fortunately for us, most of the data comes through api calls. So we can use our browser cookies to bypass this limitation and make requests to the actual api.

This is what I came up with, I hope it fits your needs:

```
import requests

def parse_item(item):
    attr_list = item['attributes']

    return {
        'name': item['name'],
        'type': item['playerType'],
        'OVR': item['composure'],
        'POS': item['position'],
        'PAC': get_attr_by_name(attr_list, 'PAC'),
        'DRI': get_attr_by_name(attr_list, 'DRI'),
        'SHO': get_attr_by_name(attr_list, 'SHO'),
        'DEF': get_attr_by_name(attr_list, 'DEF'),
        'PAS': get_attr_by_name(attr_list, 'PAS'),
        'PHY': get_attr_by_name(attr_list, 'PHY'),
    }

def get_attr_by_name(attr_list, attr_name):
    attr_name = attr_name.upper()

    try:
        return next(item['value'] for item in attr_list if item['name'].endswith(attr_name))
    except:
        return None


cookies = {
    'hl': 'us',
    'ak_bmsc': '2F856B67859A41FAFB7A62172F068FA7C99F9D14F555000037F4435B86E7E136~plcKkcciaz+3qtfstmojfDw6NLaOVQ0MD41+JJKpeGyyladBNwRB0lLcC8lVi+ELaolN0j0Yzs6HiXjknNAgxjejeFu1I32ZeiaXDNykNhtnNweIIWc26f6y1G6fcpEnkqc2shuFIGn0qSRkilVLfccdJ9pi6yVVjS09lvCSNsi8dNPeU8QUxup+jHmez3zlPebfRyk1zZ8bFb6DBiZ0Dyj6fJepQ89AJ6Kcaf5Ynd3FgefDstwDxcRbDKnssM14iLiSjwri5VWdNP4KtsmmP2as63Xxc5MaVBbTjyk2i5/o8Rj852VMkBWPlskrlkBkliBwOTM4rIFXxZhSSwO2+gog==',
    'bm_sv': '830B3A15206003312D12E0B6FB4A2696~GupjwX5n1ZUaBybPwNV8B+/mIEouVASaWGBxPDg0p/S9lbZ98ziLYDEUArV6w2sGEn7NdWMub6mV5tEsGLoEgI48TmNE1/TUwtEyJcmtg2SlGBlGzFi64B2XdCR6oL2xy92x6zdNb6kOL3U+8YaBhQxd5nutL7sFddcENkQOb3E=',
    'DOT_COM_PHPSESSID': 'e4r4ekoramipe1qvahf0fp2630',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0',
}

params = {
    'jsonParamObject': {
        'page': 1,
        'position': 'LF,CF,RF,ST,LW,LM,CAM,CDM,CM,RM,RW,LWB,LB,CB,RB,RWB'
    }
}

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item',
    params=params,
    cookies=cookies
)

items = r.json()['items']

data = [parse_item(item) for item in items]
```

The json is quite big, so I wrote a couple functions to help extract the desired data out of it.

`data` is a list of dicts. This is what a single element looks like:

```
>>> data[0]
{'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo', 'type': 'TEAM OF THE YEAR', 'OVR': 99, 'POS': 'LW', 'PAC': 98, 'DRI': 98, 'SHO': 99, 'DEF': 50, 'PAS': 94, 'PHY': 95}
```

You may need to change the values on `cookies` to the ones set by your browser.